# 500 Internal Server Error PHP Script - Tried most answers

Tags: php, fpdf

My script seems to be returning a 500 error whenever pictures are attached, however it is returning the files I wanted in my directory?  I've tried phpinfo() and put a bespoke .user.ini in my directory and I'm still ending up with the error.  I'm using Godaddy & Plesk if that helps?

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort(1);
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');

require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica','B',10);
$pdf->Image('some-url',10,10,50,50,'gif');
$pdf->SetXY(70,28);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,"Title",0,0,'C');
$pdf->SetXY(70,40);
$pdf->Cell(0,0,"Job Completion Certificate",0,0,'C');
$pdf->SetY(60);
$pdf->Write(14,$Data);
$pdf->SetY(225);
if(! empty($_POST["signature"])){
$pdf->Image($_POST["signature"],null,null,0,0,'png');
};
$pdf->AddPage('P','A4');

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG","png");
$pictures = array("file1", "file2", "file3");
$counter = 10;

foreach ($pictures as $value)
{
if ( ! empty($_FILES[$value]["tmp_name"])
&&($_FILES[$value]["size"] < 4000000)
&& in_array(end(explode(".", $_FILES[$value]["name"])), $allowedExts))
{
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$value]["tmp_name"],$_FILES[$value]["name"]);
  $pdf->Image($_FILES[$value]["name"],25,$counter,80,80);
  //unlink($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $counter += 90;
}
else
  {
  echo $value." is either Invalid or Not Attached<br>";
  };    
};
$pdf->Output($_POST["Customer"]."_".$_POST["Location"].'.pdf', 'F');

print "Data Written"; 

?>
```

If I comment out this section of the code:

```
foreach ($pictures as $value)
{
if ( ! empty($_FILES[$value]["tmp_name"])
&&($_FILES[$value]["size"] < 4000000)
&& in_array(end(explode(".", $_FILES[$value]["name"])), $allowedExts))
{
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$value]["tmp_name"],$_FILES[$value]["name"]);
  $pdf->Image($_FILES[$value]["name"],25,$counter,80,80);
  //unlink($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $counter += 90;
}
else
  {
  echo $value." is either Invalid or Not Attached<br>";
  };    
};
```

It works fine.

Edit:

After further inspection and changing my web.config file (see http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3430/disabling-windows-custom-error-messaging?locale=en&ci=46061) I get this error:

```
PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in G:\PleskVhosts\mysite\httpdocs\action.php on line 48
```

Comment: PHP is very picky about semicolons. `if, else, foreach` statements shouldn't have a semicolon, try removing those.

Comment: A 500 error in PHP means "_go look in your error log_". The full details of the error will be spelled out there. Always in development, turn up error reporting and display errors on screen.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at runtime, or set them in php.ini.

Comment: Check your `error.log` to get the cause of the 500.

Comment: The semicolons after the control structures do not belong there, but PHP won't trip over them.

Comment: Try instead of GIF image and use JPEG image, since I ran into similar situation once bot no 500 error, but code was breaking and later found fpdf does not support gif images on header or some other place.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski where would my log be kept? I have this file in the logs directory u_ex140119.log but it doesn't show anything (that I understand anyway).  I'm certain I have error reporting etc... set to ON.

Comment: @PaulBentham You'll have to consult your host's documentation to find out where they are storing your logs.  `error_reporting` needs to be turned all the way up. It is easiest to just add the two function calls from my earlier comment to the top of your PHP script, then run it.  Any errors caused by PHP will just be written to the screen then.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski if I put that in my php and i still get the error is it likely the problem isn't php?

Comment: OK, so I've put that at the top of the PHP and I still just get a general Internal Server Error message.

Comment: Then it could be an apache error, like a problem with .htaccess. You need to find your error log and look through it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski SC-Status is 500 with Substatus 19 sc win32 status 13 - can you see something in my php which would cause this?

Comment: That's no PHP error. Looks like a Windows server? The error is nondescript - google it and see what you get

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I ended up with this error: "PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in G:\PleskVhosts\mysite\httpdocs\action.php on line 48"
Line 48 is: && in_array(end(explode(".", $_FILES[$value]["name"])), $allowedExts)). How can I amend this?

Comment: @PaulBentham That's because you passed `explode()` [right into `end()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) which takes a reference as its argument. You have to store the result of `explode()` to a variable and pass that variable to `end()` so as not to violate `E_STRICT`. That shouldn't be a fatal error though, just a strict standards violation.

Comment: It seems that's what was causing the problem, thanks so much for guiding me in the right direction to an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to change my code to the below:

```
...
foreach ($pictures as $value)
{
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES[$value]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);    
if ( ! empty($_FILES[$value]["tmp_name"])
&&($_FILES[$value]["size"] < 4000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{...
```

If anyone else struggles getting errors showing up on godaddy & plesk follow the link above and put the web.config file in your root folder and the folder that your page is in.  Once you can see where the problem is it's a whole lot easier to solve!