# fpdf header not appearing

Tags: php, fpdf

I have read up on FPDF and why my header isn't showing and everyone says the same thing. I must change:

```
new FPDF()
```

into

```
new PDF()
```

which i have tried but then I get a HTTP 500 error . I have no idea why my header is not showing on the PDF documents.

My code below:

```
 <?php
 //set the question values
 $questions     = array(
 'name' => "Name: ",
 'date' => "Date: ",
 'first' => "First Day of Leave: ",
 'last' => "Last Day of Leave: ",
 'days' => "Number of Days Taken: ",
 'email' => "Managers Email: ",
 'sig' => "Signed: "

);
//set the question answers
$date          = $_POST['date'];
$first         = $_POST['first'];
$last          = $_POST['last'];
$days          = $_POST['days'];
$email         = $_POST['email'];
$sig           = $_POST['sig'];
$name          = $_POST['name'];
//set the question names
$questionName  = $questions['name'];
$questionDate  = $questions['date'];
$questionFirst = $questions['first'];
$questionLast  = $questions['last'];
$questionDays  = $questions['days'];
$questionEmail = $questions['email'];
$questionSig   = $questions['sig'];
//Create the PDF
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF {
function Header() {
    $this->Image('http://domain.co.uk/img/quote-header.png', 10, 6, 30);
    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
    $this->Cell(80);
    $this->Cell(30, 10, 'Title', 1, 0, 'C');
    $this->Ln(20);
}
}

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
//insert questions and answers
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionDate, $date));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionName, $name));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionFirst, $first));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionLast, $last));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionDays, $days));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(150, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionEmail, $email));
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->MultiCell(50, 10, sprintf("%s %s", $questionSig, $sig));
//display pdf
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222079/500-internal-server-error-php-script-tried-most-answers   _A 500 error in PHP means "go look in your error log"_

Comment: try to disable the Image Part: $this->Image('http://domain.co.uk/img/quote-header.png', 10, 6, 30);   maybe FPDF stumble over the not available domainname....

Comment: @ChristianFelix tried that sir still nothing appears. No errors. Just nothing appears for the header

Answer (score 0):

If you create the object with `$pdf = new FPDF()` then the constructor of the parent class `FPDF` is called and not the constructor of the child class `PDF`. In the parent class, the `Header()` function is empty, that is why nothing appears. You must create the object with `$pdf = new PDF()` and then your custom `Header()` function will be called every time a page is added.

After making that change, I tested your code and it works when I use an image URL that really exists. If I use a URL that does not exist, PHP will complain that the HTTP request failed. If I remove the `$this->Image('http://...')` line, the error goes away and it prints just 'Title' in the header, as you would expect.